# Available approaches to creating an object instance from JSON data at startup

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, optimization, startup

I'm currently developing an application that will manipulate and read from a single global object.
The data is available in JSON, and the object is being created at application startup.

The global object (Book) is used to hold an array of classes (Chapters) instantiated from the JSON data. Moreover, each (Chapter) holds an array of (Verse).

My concern is that the array of chapters, and array of verses are created on each startup. The application will be an offline Mobile app.

1- Is this necessary ? Or can the global object be created once and then loaded thereafter.
2- If so, then what is the optimum way to achieve this in JavaScript with and without OOP.

---

- The Book will be of fixed size the chapters and verses will not increase in number.
- The reason for creating the verse and chapter instances is to allow for commenting and tagging each chapter and verse instance. Selecting multiple verses under one theme.
- Other than the text, the chapter has more fields than what's been shown, for ex. translation, array of themes [] etc.

My idea was to have one object that can be read and modified to represent the Book. Please advise what approach would be better.

Thank you

Simplified Typescript code

```
    import data from 'data.json' assert {type: "json"}

    // Classes
    import Chapter from './class/chapter.js'
    import Verse from './class/chapter.js'

    const Book = data.map((chapter, index)=>{
        const verses = chapter.verses.map(
            (verse, index) => new Verse(index, verse.txt)
        );
        return new Chapter(
            index,
            chapter.name, 
            verses,
        );
    })
```

Comment: Is data already json? do you need to modify json?

Comment: "My concern is that the array of chapters, and array of verses are created on each startup": Why is this a concern? How would you do otherwise?

Comment: @depperm Yes the data is in json.

Comment: @BrunoMarotta I am asking if that is necessary each time the app is opened. Can it not be performed once in dev, and then the loaded in prod.

Comment: Not sure if this is going to be scalable; what if the object got so large? Your browser will become slower, and your app will start crawling.

Comment: What is the alternative? Writing a lot of of new Book, Chapter and Verse statements? Why you need to instantiate these classes and cannot use the json directly?

Comment: You can also take a look on this repo: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer . Not sure if it is more performant than what you are already doing

Comment: "*can the global object be created once and then loaded thereafter*" - not sure what you mean by "loaded thereafter". Creating an object only once is exactly what your `const Book = data.map(…)` code is doing.

Comment: @BrunoMarotta Thank you. I think the link you shared is what I am searching for. It might not be better like you said but I think its worth a look.

Comment: @Bergi, Since the Book Is large ~600 pages. My concern matched that of Deano's in that it might slow the app with all theses instantiated classes. I am considering creating a separate User Object which will contain the users comments/notes while keeping the Book as a readonly object.

Comment: @Omar 600 objects is nothing. Also, making an object readonly has nothing to do with memory consumption; if anything, separate read- and write-objects will be less efficient.

Comment: @Bergi, Thank you for clarifying that. If I go ahead with this approach I'll end up with a minimum of ~6700 class instances.  I would have assumed having an object tracking the users additions only will be more efficient?

Comment: @Omar Additions to what? You still have the objects representing the book, they ain't become less.

Comment: @Bergi, The plan is to allow the user to add notes and collate different verses together under different themes. I believe Having an instance for each verse with a field for a user note or tags is neater, but I worry that its overkill. Whereas, if I only track the changes then I can have less than the maximum 6500 instances. I have no experience in optimizing an app so I'm not sure how either approach will effect the app. Thank you

Comment: Then go for the "neater" design first, and [optimise later iff you actually need to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that my app required instantiating ~6000 class instances at startup I was concerned that there may be a cleaner approach.
I realized to add my desired app functionality, I can either continue with this or have a more complicated design in which the additions to each verse will be stored separately.

I've decided to continue with the simpler design following advise from the contributors.